# X Shared Y's Something

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-usage

I was looking up information about popes and then I found this:

> [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sexually_active_popes#Popes_accused_of_having_male_lovers_during_pontificate)
>   Pope Julius III (1550–1555) was alleged to have had a long affair with Innocenzo Ciocchi del Monte. The Venetian ambassador at that time reported that I***nnocenzo shared the pope's bed.***

Should the marked portion be changed to either "Innocenzo slept in the pope's bed" or "Innocenzo shared a bed with the pope"?

Other examples I found on the web suggest this usage:   For a hypothetical example with two people, Mike and John, and a shareable object, a table, which is owned by Mike, I could write only:

- "Mike and John share a table"
- "Mike shares a table with John"
- "John shares a table with Mike"

  but not "John shares Mike's table". Any suggestions from this forum's members?

Comment: Could it be that the examples you found on the web didn't know to whom the table belonged to? "John shares Mike's table" is perfectly acceptable in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

No, you've misunderstood the clause *Innocenzo shared the pope's bed*. It's a euphemistic way of saying that Innocenzo and the Pope were homosexual lovers and *slept together* (i.e., had sexual relations) in the Pope's bed. Changing the words changes the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I see OP's confusion. Two people could share a something. One person could share a something with another. But to write "John shares Mike's table" seems incomplete; the sentence should be continued like "John shares Mike's table with...."

Comment: At http://thinkexist.com/dictionary/meaning/share/ : **Share** (v. t.) To partake of, use, or experience, [along] with others. However, "John shares Mike's table" is idiomatic (and rather old-fashioned sounding) for "John enjoys Mike's hospitality". "John shares Mike's car" is non-idiomatic, and shows this particular transitive usage more clearly.